# Refer to the entire list count instead of View count

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, html

I have this HTML code snippet, which is supposed to count the existing list items, to be used for token generation by adding 1 to it.

But somehow its only counting the items that end user is able to see through view defined (restricted for user to see only item created by him) rather than taking the count of the entire list (regardless of users)

Appreciate your input/help on this.

```
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"type = "text/javascript" ></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
var clientContext = null;
var web = null;
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(AutoGenerate, "sp.js");

function AutoGenerate() {
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = clientContext.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query></Query></View>');
    this.listItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(listItems);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onListItemsLoadSuccess),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onListItemsLoadSuccess(sender, args) {

    var AutoIncremental = "SOSR-" + listItems.get_count();
    $("input[title^='Request ID']").val(AutoIncremental);
    $("input[title^='Request ID']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of items obtained in this way should only be related to the number of items that the user has permission to view, and the view settings will not affect the results.
My test results also support my point:

[image]

[image]